# Why is my css transition not working when i add a class to it

Tags: css

so i was making a modal box and i want a button that adds an overlay when you clicked it. So i made the overlay here's the css:

```
.overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

and then i added this class in a press of an element

```
.oa{
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;

}
```

here's the html

```
div id="maincon">
 <div class="overlay"></div>
<div id="secmaincon">
<div class="container">

    <div class="formtitle"><h1>Add Book</h1></div>
    <form action="" method="post" class="inputs"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="inputs">
        {% for field in form %}

        <div class="input">
        <label for="" class="labelinput">{{field.label}}</label>
        {{field}}
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
        <div class="input">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    
    

</div>
<div class="gc">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="data" id="test">
            <div class="num"><p>1</p></div>
            <div class="title"><p>Crush It</p></div>
            <div class="author"><p>Gary Vaynerchunk</p></div>
            <div class="ISBN"><p>132132312</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="num"><p>2</p></div>
            <div class="title"><p>Crush It</p></div>
            <div class="author"><p>Gary Vaynerchunk</p></div>
            <div class="ISBN"><p>132132312</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="num"><p>3</p></div>
            <div class="title"><p>Crush It</p></div>
            <div class="author"><p>Gary Vaynerchunk</p></div>
            <div class="ISBN"><p>132132312</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src='{% static "js/booklist.js" %}'></script>
</div>
```

the javascript did it's job and adds the the class. everything works fine except the transition didn't happen it just renders out a big black screen without the transition. is there any css code I've written that prevents it?

Comment: would you mind sharing the html as well for testing purposes?

Comment: @xstrafez_ there but html a bit weird cause i was using django you can definitely replace the weird parts with just an inputs

Comment: Oh nvm, try removing the display none and block and see if it works. see [codepen](https://codepen.io/sshimabuku/pen/eYZedwj). if you uncomment the display property, the transition doesn't work anymore for some reason

Comment: @xstrafez_ thanks man!